# Issue with Dataframe manipulation on Python

Tags: python, pandas

Have the below panda data frame. Trying to create a new column labeled *Category* with the index of sorted unique values of *Color* by its *Fruit* type.

**Data:**

[image]

```
sorted(df(Fruit="Citrus").unique()) => ['Green', 'Orange', 'Yellow']
sorted(df(Fruit="Apples").unique()) => ['Dark Red', 'Green', 'Red']
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
import panda as pd

data = {'Fruit': ['Citrus', 'Apples', 'Apples', 'Citrus', 'Citrus', 'Apples', 'Citrus', 'Apples', 'Citrus', 'Apples'],
    'Color': ['Orange', 'Dark Red', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Dark Red', 'Yellow', 'Green']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Category'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['Color'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(sorted(x.unique()))[0][x.argsort()])

print(df)
```

Python is complaining, which I believe has to do with the newly created *Category* column.

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Questions:

1. What is the right way to attend to this error.
2. Is there any simpler way to implement this, as will be having 100,000 rows to process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['Category'] = (df.groupby('Fruit')['Color']
                    .rank('dense')
                    .sub(1).astype(int)
                 )
```

Alternatively, fix your code by not using the unique values but all of them:

```
df['Category'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['Color'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(sorted(x))[0][x.argsort()])
```

Output:

```
    Fruit     Color  Category
0  Citrus    Orange         1
1  Apples  Dark Red         0
2  Apples       Red         2
3  Citrus    Orange         1
4  Citrus     Green         0
5  Apples       Red         2
6  Citrus    Yellow         2
7  Apples  Dark Red         0
8  Citrus    Yellow         2
9  Apples     Green         1
```